# How to parse JSON data to generate a C# sample code which demonstrates Request Body Object creation

Tags: c#, json, rest, api

I need to write many sample codes for various API's, which demonstrate how to write the code to use those particular REST API's in C# language.

Now for the API's which are HTTP POST calls, a request body is first created as a class object which is then later serialized into a JSON string and passed to the REST Client.

My Requirement is in this part: "**Creating the request Body as a class object**".

Following example will make the requirement crystal clear:-

Suppose i have the below JSON Data:

```
{        
  "workingDays": ["Monday","Wednesday","Friday"],
  "employeeInformation": {
      "employeeID": "12345",
      "name": {
          "firstName": "foo",
          "lastName": "bar"
        }
    },
   "joiningDate":"23061984"
}
```

I need to parse the above data and generate the below code (***which currently i am writing manually***):

```
// Create Main Request Body Object
var requestBodyObj = new RequestBody();

// Array Case
var workingDaysObj = new List<string>();
workingDaysObj.Add("Monday");
workingDaysObj.Add("Wednesday");
workingDaysObj.Add("Friday");

requestBodyObj.workingDays = workingDaysObj;

// Nested Object Case
var employeeInformationObj = new employeeInformation();

employeeInformationObj.employeeID = "12345";

var nameObj = new name();
nameObj.firstName = "foo";
nameObj.lastName = "bar";

employeeInformationObj.name = nameObj;

requestBodyObj.employeeInformation = employeeInformationObj;

// Simple Name/Value Pair
requestBodyObj.joiningDate = "23061984";
```

So as per the above example the JSON Data can be in one of the following 2 forms as well (apart from simple name/value pairs):

1. Array
2. Nested Object

And both these cases should be handled as shown in the above code.

**Note:** User will not be provided with a JSON file so i can't write any code which directly reads a JSON file, deserializes it and assigns the values to a class object using (for example) a NewtonSoft function:

```
// read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type
Movie movie1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\movie.json"));

// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\movie.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Movie movie2 = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Movie));
}
```

I just want a simple "JSON parser and C# Code generator" (Preferably written in C# language itself).

Any suggestions or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple answer here. I do think that choosing a scripting language , say Python, for the job will make your task easier.

Comment: I have uploaded a solution.
Kindly let me know if it needs any refactoring or if there's a better alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit Update**

- Pascal Case setting for variable names
- Json Object names can be mapped to Project model classes
- Write the output to text file for easy copy

Updated Code Below:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SampleCodeCreator
{
    class Program
    {
        // Declaring the variables
        static string jsonFilePath = @"[Your File Path]";
        static string outputFilePath = @"[Your File Path]";
        static string  jsonData;
        static Dictionary<string, string> classMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            // Initializing Class map which is used to map the json object to Project Model Class
            InitializeClassMap();

            // clear current data in the output file
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFilePath, false))
            {
                file.Write(String.Empty);
            }

            // read the json data file and store the data in a simple string
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonFilePath))
            {
                jsonData = r.ReadToEnd();                
            }

            // Call the method for the whole json data
            PrintJsonObject("RequestBody", jsonData);            
        }        

        static void PrintJsonObject(string parentObject, string jsonData)
        {
            // if the parent object has any mapped class, then set the object name
            parentObject = MappedClass(parentObject);

            Console.WriteLine("var {0}Obj = new {1}();", ToCamelCase(parentObject), parentObject);
            SetOutput("var " + ToCamelCase(parentObject) + "Obj = new " + parentObject + "();");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            SetOutput("");


            // Deserialize the Json data and iterate through each of its sub-sections
            var jsonSubData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);
            foreach (var data in jsonSubData)
            {
                var dataKey = data.Key;
                var dataValue = data.Value;

                // array case (if the sub element is an array)
                if (dataValue.ToString().Contains("["))
                {
                    PrintArrayCase(dataKey, dataValue);

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}Obj.{1} = {1}Obj;", ToCamelCase(parentObject), dataKey);
                    SetOutput(ToCamelCase(parentObject) + "Obj." + dataKey + " = " + dataKey + "Obj;");

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    SetOutput("");

                }
                // nested object case (if the sub element itself contains another json format body)
                else if (dataValue.ToString().Contains("{"))
                {
                    // Recursive Call
                    PrintJsonObject(dataKey, dataValue.ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}Obj.{1} = {1}Obj;", ToCamelCase(parentObject), dataKey);
                    SetOutput(ToCamelCase(parentObject) + "Obj." + dataKey + " = " + dataKey + "Obj;");

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    SetOutput("");
                }
                // simple key value pair case
                else
                {
                    PrintKeyValuePairCase(parentObject, dataKey, dataValue.ToString());                    
                }
            }            
        }

        static void PrintArrayCase(string key, object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("var {0}Obj = new List<string>();", key);
            SetOutput("var " + key + "Obj = new List<string>();");

            // The array value is split into its values
            // e.g. [abc, def, ghi]  -> [abc] [def] [ghi]
            var valueString = obj.ToString();
            var valueSplitArray = valueString.Split(',');
            for (int k = 0; k < valueSplitArray.Count(); k++)
            {
                string listValue = "";
                if (k != valueSplitArray.Count() - 1)
                {
                    var startIndex = valueSplitArray[k].IndexOf("\"");
                    listValue = valueSplitArray[k].Substring(startIndex + 1, valueSplitArray[k].Length - startIndex - 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    var startIndex = valueSplitArray[k].IndexOf("\"");
                    listValue = valueSplitArray[k].Substring(startIndex + 1, valueSplitArray[k].Length - startIndex - 5);
                }

                // each value is then added to the main list object
                Console.WriteLine(@"{0}Obj.Add(""{1}"");", ToCamelCase(key), listValue);
                SetOutput(@""+ToCamelCase(key)+@"Obj.Add("""+listValue+@""");");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            SetOutput("");
        }

        static void PrintKeyValuePairCase(string parentObj, string key, string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}Obj.{1} = \"{2}\";", ToCamelCase(parentObj), key, value);
            SetOutput("" + ToCamelCase(parentObj) + "Obj." + key + " = \"" + value + "\";");
        }

        static string ToCamelCase(string str)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                return str.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        static string MappedClass(string str)
        {
            if (classMap.ContainsKey(str))
                return classMap[str];
            else
                return str;
        }

        static void InitializeClassMap()
        {
            classMap.Add("employeeInformation", "EmployeeInfo");            
        }

        static void SetOutput(string str)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFilePath, true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```